# Update a value while publishing a site for Docusaurus 1.*

Tags: reactjs

While publishing my site I want to make an external call (I am using "got" to do this) and retrieve some value from there (in my example below it is "total_count"). An example below is part of index.js:

```js
const Showcase = () => {
    const got = require('got');

    got("http://aaa.bbb.com", {
        json: true
    }).then(response => {
        console.log("ms: " + response.body.total_count);
        got.ms = response.body.total_count;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.body);
    });
    ...

    return (.. < div > < /h3><h2>{got.ms}</h2 > < /div> <
        /div>
    );
};
```

I am able to retrieve this value I see it in a console:

```
$ docusaurus-publish
master    
generate.js triggered...
feed.js triggered...
sitemap.js triggered...
Site built successfully. Generated files in 'build' folder.
ms: 112
Cloning into '...'...
master
Note: checking out 'origin/gh-pages'.
```

However, this value never rendered and appears on an actual site. I think this is happening because an actual build happened BEFORE I made a call, so it is too late to have an update for value:

```
Site built successfully. Generated files in 'build' folder.
ms: 112
```

My question, what would be a way to solve this issue?